# hadoop cluster clarification

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie in hadoop and I am trying to run a hadoop jar on Amazon EC2. I have started my amazon ec2 instance through the console, uploaded my files to the dfs and then was able to successfully run the job jar and generate output on the instance.

But still I am confused on one part. I am not sure if the job was run on a single machine in amazon ec2 or was it ran on a cluster? How do I find the number of worker nodes involved for my jar run?

In some reference links I see we have to use launch-cluster command , for example "bin/hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster test-cluster 2" . What is the difference in starting the instance from the console and using this command like launch-cluster.

Comment: Is there a reason why are using EC2 instead of EMR? If you start 1 EC2 instance than your cluster will consist of 1 machine.